# Do I have to sacrifice non-token dragons to Day of the Dragons?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The Card [Day of the Dragons](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=43602) says the following:

[image: Day of the Dragons card]

> When Day of the Dragons leaves the battlefield, **sacrifice all Dragons you control**. Then return the exiled cards to the battlefield under your control.

Note the part I've highlighted. What exactly does that mean?

For example, if I invoke a dragon card after using the enchantment ([Dromar, the Banisher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23206) for example), when the enchantment leaves play do I have to sacrifice both my 5/5 Dragon tokens **and** Dromar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you would have to sacrifice all dragons creatures and creature tokens under your control, regardless of where they came from or when they were cast. *All Dragons* means all permanents (creatures, tokens) that have have *Dragon* in their supertype or subtype. "Under your control" should be clear.

Comment: Since it say *you control*, if I cast a card control (instant) on an opponent's dragon before the enchantment leaves play, I'll have to destroy it also, right? Anyways, that's sad I have to destroy dragons unrelated to the enchantment also. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was trying to get at with "regardless of where they came from". Similarly, you would sacrifice any Dragon tokens under your control created by any other spells/abilities.

Comment: pair this with a clever use of [Ego erasure](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=139692) and [Naturalize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370802) and you can get all your creatures back and keep all your dragons.

Comment: @Pow-Ian This combo is so pretty and cheap mana cost! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question, I would not have thought of it if you hadn't.